# Change which local git repo Qt Creator uses

Tags: git, qt, qt-creator

How can I change which local git repository Qt Creator uses?

Currently, it is pointing at the git repo in my ~/qt5projects/myproj/.git folder.

I would like to change it to the git repo in my ~/.git folder.

How can I do this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply open a project in your home folder that is *not* in the `~/qt5projects/myproj` folder. Or just rename `~/qt5projects/myproj/.git` to something else (say `.oldgit`).

When git invoked by Qt Creator is looking for the repository, it searches *outwards* from the folder the project file is in, that git was invoked in.

Also note that in your repeated questions, you talk of "Qt". Qt isn't doing anything because it's a software development framework. Qt Creator, the IDE that you're using, is doing that.